# javascript-----what's conflict of my javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

The site is hostingcouponsclub.com. I want to add a text tip "Click to copy & open site" effect to the yellow coupon code, which is near the scissors.  But the tooltip is not working when I put this code to my local environment. It's ok. I think maybe there is a conflict with the "Click to copy & open site" JavaScript. How do I correct it? Thank you. This is the tooltip code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".coupon-code").hover(
        function() { $(this).contents(".coupontooltip").show(); },
        function() { $(this).contents("span:last-child").css({  display: "none" }); }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML Markup in the [site](http://hostingcouponsclub.com/) is,

```
<div rel="http://www.godaddy.com/" class="coupon-code hover">
    BNX5246Lmg
    <span class="coupontooltip" style="display: none;">Click to copy &amp; open site</span>
</div>
<div rel="http://www.godaddy.com/" class="coupon-code hover">
    BNX5246Lmg2
    <span class="coupontooltip" style="display: none;">Click to copy &amp; open site2</span>
</div>
```

Made these changes.

1. Took away <strike>`display: none;`</strike> from the *coupontooltip css class*
2. Change toolTipHover.js like this:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".coupon-code").hover(
           function () { $(this).find(".coupontooltip").show(); },
           function () { $(this).find(".coupontooltip").hide(); }
       );
   });
   ```

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/WMYF2/) to see it working

Comment: i did as you told, but it still can't work. when you put the mouse over the yellow box, the class is changing. maybe my cliboard is wrong

Comment: its because of the flash content you have put there. why is it necessary?

Comment: the  flash is used to copy the discount code to the clipboard.but this site (retailmenot.com),the "click to copy & open site" can work,but i don't know how that site do?

Answer (score 0):

`.contents()` doesn't work like that at all. Are you looking for `$(".coupontooltip", this)` and `$("span:last-child", this)` ?

Comment: sorry,i am a newbie of javascript, i can't understand you well.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
function() { $(this).find('.coupontooltip').show(); },
function() { $(this).find('span:last-child').css("display", "none"); }
```

as the arguments to the `hover` bind.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".coupon-code").hover(
        function() { $(this).children(".coupontooltip").show(); },
        function() { $(this).children("span:last-child").css({  display: "none" }); }
    );
});
```

The [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) are same except that the former will get the text and comments nodes as well.